# How do I (permanently) change TTL on an Apple Time Capsule? For Airport on Mac I did it with “sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.ttl=65”

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, apple, ttl

On our countryside farm we have only mobile connections. I had to place a mobile router with a SIM card on the roof so I can use internet. But hotspot is limited.

I changed TTL on Mac to avoid tethering (hotspot) detection so I can get full speed from my mobile connection as [explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48408/76120):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.ttl=65
```

Good! It works!

Yet we would also would like to use our phones and smart TV beamer without reducing our hotspot limitation. Internet data is unlimited but not on hotspot.

So I imagined attaching an old Apple Time Capsule on the router via LAN. And the Time Capsule will tether the mobile phone plus the smart TV.

#### Is there an option to change the TTL on Time Capsule configuration?

FWIW, I am changing the TTL so the phone company doesn’t detect the tethering as [explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48408/76120). If I connect *without* the TTL change the phone company will detect I am tethering (using a hotspot) and limit my bandwidth.

---

Unfathomable the routers config bin:

[image]

Comment: When all is said and done, you should probably forget about the Time Capsule and purchase a basic router that can run OpenWRT or DD-WRT which is more flexible and can handle things like TTL changes.

Comment: @harrymc .•* it is a S9930-LTE Ricon.

Comment: @harrymc I attached a config screenshot of the routers cfg bin

Comment: A screenshot of a binary file doesn't help. You should login to the router and try to find a setting that helps with the TTL problem.

Comment: There’s not much to relate I’m going to crypt the file and hoping that what we r looking for is inside if not there are some basic settings on the ui like standard dhcp. Tomorrow I call the router’s technical department

Comment: That image (PNG) of the binary config file is utterly useless. Why post it? It has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple never provided a way to adjust the TTL on any model of the AirPort Base Station product line, including Time Capsules.

Comment: I tricked Apple products several times. like once as I could not buy a wifi module for a Mac Pro after purchasing .... so I plugged a lan cable from the Mac Pro into an airport utility :)     now idk what to do... :( the phone company does not provide us with extensions or a different contract. I mean I already have unlimited unfortunately the hotspot is not.

Comment: @ErdemErdem If I were in your situation, I'd look for a router that can run OpenWRT (or another Linux router firmware distro). That way you've got the full power of a Unix-like networking stack you can tweak any way you want. Or maybe a router from a company with a reputation for products that cater to nerds by exposing all the nerd-knobs, like maybe MikroTik or someone like that. The last AirPort Time Capsules were awesome, but they are almost a decade old now and only support Wi-Fi 5. Wi-Fi 7 is hitting the market now. Time for something more modern.

Comment: I had that on my mind awesome pal also.... I like cable plus oldskool stuff ;D still buying headphones wo bt